# Azure DocumentDB does not create document when using attribute [JsonIgnore] on property

Tags: json, azure, serialization, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing the next class bellow as an object to DocumentDB service.
Using

```
Client.CreateDocumentAsync("dbs/" + DBId + "/colls/" + CollectionId, document);
```

When removing the attribute [JsonIgnore] it's work fine, with the attribute it does not write to the DB. Not even throw exception.

The Classs being written to the DB

```
public class BaseLogData
{
    public int CreationTimeEpoch { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime CreationTime
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(CreationTimeEpoch);
        }
        set
        {
            CreationTimeEpoch = TimeUtils.ToEpoch(value);
        }
    }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public int? ThreadId { get; set; }
    public string CallerFilePath { get; set; }
    public string CallerMemberName { get; set; }
    public int? CallerLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public string InnerException { get; set; }

    public string LogLevel
    {
        get
        {
            return _LogLevel.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            _LogLevel = (eLogLevel)Enum.Parse(typeof(eLogLevel), value);
        }
    }
    private eLogLevel _LogLevel { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Does it write nothing to DocumentDB with the [JsonIgnore] attribute or does it just suppress the DateTime? I'm not sure of the differences between them but there is also [IgnoreDataMember] and [ScriptIgnore] attributes.

Comment: unable to repro using .NET 1.5.2 SDK. i don't see an id property on your class, so are you sure this works when just removing the JsonIgnore attribute (you can't insert a doc without an id property) ? I have a class Foo { public string id {get;set;} [JsonIgnore] public string Exclude {get; set;} } and when i insert a new one of these, i get a document with just an id property. as expected.

Comment: It works without an id property, it is created by it self in the DB. Even when adding the "id" property it stay with the same problem. I'm using .NET 1.5.2 SDK. Is there a way to follow the process deeper, see whats happen in the serialization process ?

Comment: so thinking there was something with your specific class somewhere, i took the class definition above and could create a document without any trouble. 

if you refer to http://1drv.ms/1RRoTtQ you will see my solution and a screenshot showing the resulting document created as expected.

Comment: any word on this@guyAssaf? I cannot replicate the behavior you predict. You can contact us via askdocdb.com if you like and we can dig in to this in more detail.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to build a clean project and contact you with that.